problem with fetchall when inserting multiple rows using sqlalchemy
Good Afternoon,
I am using psycopg and sqlalchemy to make an insert into and returning query.
I have successfully inserted and returned, but in a roundabout way.
I am inserting the data and returning the values in a temporary table and then selecting the values in the temporary table, as shown below.
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy import bindparam
import psycopg

def makePgEngine():
        global pgEngine
        pgEngine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg://postgres:postgres@localhost:5412/postgres")

def insert_into_returning():
        makePgEngine()
        sql_text = "with r as (insert into public.numeric_data_source (x_field,y_field,z_field)values(:x_field,:y_field,:z_field) returning x_field, y_field, z_field) insert into temp_numeric_data_source (x_field, y_field, z_field)select x_field, y_field, z_field from r"
        qry =text(sql_text).bindparams(
            bindparam('x_field'),
            bindparam('y_field'),
            bindparam('z_field')
                )
        params=({'x_field':-99,'y_field':-98,'z_field':-97},
                            {'x_field':-98,'y_field':-97,'z_field':-96},
                            {'x_field':-97,'y_field':-96,'z_field':-95})
        with pgEngine.connect() as con:
            con.execute(text("truncate table public.numeric_data_source"))
            con.execute(text("create temp table temp_numeric_data_source as select x_field, y_field, z_field from public.numeric_data_source"))
            con.execute(qry, params)
            data=con.execute(text("select * from temp_numeric_data_source"))
            print(data.fetchall())
            con.commit()

Is there a way I can get around the use of the temporary table? I would like to retain the use of the text object in sqlalchemy. Thank you for your assistance.

Why are you populating a temp table with parameters to only query same data back? You also clear out the final, non-temp table with truncate after inserting with temp table. To avoid the XY Problem, please explain in words your overall need.

I am trying to do an INSERT INTO RETURNING. I do not really want the temp table. Given the situation if nit returning data from the insert l, using the temo table seemed like the only option.


Your code shows psycopg and your tag is psycopg2, they are not the same thing. If you are indeed using psycopg then the tag should be psycopg3. 2) Not sure how truncate table public.numeric_data_source then create temp table temp_numeric_data_source as select x_field, y_field, z_field from public.numeric_data_source is going to do anything useful? Because this select * from temp_numeric_data_source will be empty. 3) Why not  just work in psycopg and avoid SQLAlchemy?


Avoiding sqlalchemy in this situation might be an option since I have already done bulk inserts with returning using just psycopg3. Sqlalchemy has some advantages since I normally (though not in this situation) can avoid worrying about the intricacies of sql syntax with sqlalchemy. I am working with multiple database systems.

I think it is probably easiest to just specify the table you are working with rather than trying to force text() to generate an appropriate query.  Something like this:
# table and column are more basic versions of Table and Column
from sqlalchemy import table, insert, column

def populate(conn):
    values = [
        {'x_field':-99,'y_field':-98,'z_field':-97},
        {'x_field':-98,'y_field':-97,'z_field':-96},
        {'x_field':-97,'y_field':-96,'z_field':-95}
    ]
    numeric_data_source_t2 = table("numeric_data_source",
        column("id"),
        column("x_field"),
        column("y_field"),
        column("z_field"))
    result = conn.execute(insert(numeric_data_source_t2).returning(numeric_data_source_t2), values)

    for row in result:
        print (row)

    conn.commit()

Here is a more complicated version using Table.
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Integer, Column, Float
from sqlalchemy.sql import insert

# Tables that need to work together need to be in the same metadata but we just use one here.
metadata = MetaData()

# This only minimally defines a table for the purpose of generating an insert.
numeric_data_source_t = Table("numeric_data_source", metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("x_field", Float),
    Column("y_field", Float),
    Column("z_field", Float))

def insert_into_returning(conn):
    values = [
        {'x_field':-99,'y_field':-98,'z_field':-97},
        {'x_field':-98,'y_field':-97,'z_field':-96},
        {'x_field':-97,'y_field':-96,'z_field':-95}
    ]
    # Insert the data and return it back along with its id.
    result = conn.execute(insert(numeric_data_source_t).returning(numeric_data_source_t), values)
    for row in result:
        print(row)
    conn.commit()


Maybe someone can chime in on how to force text() insert an insert() to then specify returning() with columns but I could not find a way.

It actually returns a row if I only insert one row of data at a time, but in this instance where I am inseeting three rows in bulk it does not return data

In my test code it returns 3 rows.  Were you using insert() with the table() spec ?

I just implemented your code and it works perfectly. Regarding the code that I originally posted for the question, it only works if I insert one row at a time. Thank you for your assistance.

So I can see the advantage of your code, this works well with pandas data. I can take the dataframe and convert it to a tuple of dictionaries, and that manages the bulk insert and returning data.

Just to add one more point. I made variations to your code, including making connection to oracledb with consistently successful results. Yours is the way to go.

I was able to get rows by editing the code as shown below:
def insert_into_returning():
        makePgEngine()
        sql_text = "insert into public.numeric_data_source (x_field,y_field,z_field)values(:x_field,:y_field,:z_field),(:x_field1,:y_field1,:z_field1),(:x_field2,:y_field2,:z_field2) returning x_field, y_field, z_field"
        qry =text(sql_text).bindparams(
            bindparam('x_field'),
            bindparam('y_field'),
            bindparam('z_field'),
            bindparam('x_field1'),
            bindparam('y_field1'),
            bindparam('z_field1'),
            bindparam('x_field2'),
            bindparam('y_field2'),
            bindparam('z_field2')                )
        params=({'x_field':-99,'y_field':-98,'z_field':-97,'x_field1':-98,'y_field1':-97,'z_field1':-96,'x_field2':-97,'y_field2':-96,'z_field2':-95})
        with pgEngine.connect() as con:
            con.execute(text("truncate table public.numeric_data_source"))
            data=con.execute(qry, params)
            print(data.fetchall())
            con.commit()

This seems to indicate that sqlalchemy returns the output of RETURNING for single sets of data at a time, like this:
sql_text = "insert into public.numeric_data_source (x_field,y_field,z_field)values(:x_field,:y_field,:z_field),(:x_field1,:y_field1,:z_field1),(:x_field2,:y_field2,:z_field2) returning x_field, y_field, z_field"
.....

params=({'x_field':-99,'y_field':-98,'z_field':-97,'x_field1':-98,'y_field1':-97,'z_field1':-96,'x_field2':-97,'y_field2':-96,'z_field2':-95})

I guess this is progress, but really not the direction I was hoping for. I will try the answer suggested by @ian-wilson
